# How to use FirebaseListAdapter with 2 layouts

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, chat

So I want to make a chat app with the help of the  `Firebase API`  but it seems that I can't change between layout for specific items (e.g: Sent and received messages). I found a way but it's not efficient and this method is like this: I make 1 layout whit the model for Sent and Received message and after that I wold hide the Sent box if the message is received and hide the Received Box if the Message is sent 
I use this for my adapter:

```
mPostAdapterChat = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Chat, ChatViewHolder>(
            Chat.class,
            R.layout.item_layout_chat,
            ChatViewHolder.class,
            mChatRef
    )
```

So do you guys have some methods how can I use 2 layout and change between them for every item (e.g Sent and received message) or do you know another way how can I do it better than using  `gone/visibile`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can actually do this:

1) In your chat class, identify which type of message it is: send or receive. Add an attribute or create a method like `isSent()` to check if it's a send message or a receive message. I'll use an `isSent()` method as an example.

2) Override the method `getItemViewType` in your recycler view adapter and return an int representing the type (e.g. 0 for send and 1 for receive)

```
@Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        Chat chat = this.getItem(position);
        if(chat.isSent()){
           return 0;
         }else{
           return 1;
         }
    }
```

To get an item in your `RecyclerViewAdapter` override getItem:

```
@Override
public Chat getItem(int pos) {
    return super.getItem(getCount() - 1 - pos);
}
```

3) In your `onCreateViewHolder` method you'll have access to the view type so you can simply inflate a different layout depending on the view type.

```
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
         switch (viewType) {
             case 0: //inflate and return view holder type 0
             case 1: //inflate and return view holder type 1
         }
    }
```

Comment: How should i Initialize the chatList? can you give me an example?

Comment: sorry, you're using the recyclerviewadapter, so it's better to use getItem, checkout my edit :)